# Unable to pupulate dropdown from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Cannot populate dropdown from database. View is throwing error "undefined variable $acciones". I'm trying to show dropdown list and save selected item into database but i don't know what am i doing wrong here.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="acciones">Acciones</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <?php foreach ($acciones as $accion) { ?>
                                   <!-- <input id="acciones" name="acciones" placeholder="P.ej: cargar" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text"> -->
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="acciones">-Seleccione acción-</label>    
                            <select id="acciones" name="acciones">
                                    <option value="<?php echo $accion->idAcciones; ?>" <?php echo set_select('acciones', $accion->idAcciones); ?>>
                                        <?php echo $class->nombreAccion; ?>
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <span class="help-block"> </span>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function profile() {


        if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Por favor, regístrese para poder ver esta página.");
            redirect("auth/login");
        }

        if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
            //$data['city_list'] = $this->City_model->get_dropdown_list();
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('datepicker', 'Fecha', 'required|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('acciones', 'Acciones', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('numeroentrega', 'Numero entrega', 'required|trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cliente', 'Cliente', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('origen', 'Orígen', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('destino', 'Destino', 'required');


            // if form validation true
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                $data1 = array('cita' => $_POST['datepicker']);

                $data = array(
                    'idAcciones' => $_POST['acciones'],
                    'numeroEntrega' => md5($_POST['numeroentrega']),
                    'cliente' => $_POST['cliente'],
                    'origen' => $_POST['origen'],
                    'destino' => md5($_POST['destino'])
                );
                $this->db->insert('citas', $data1);
                $this->db->insert('entregas', $data);

                $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "¡Sus datos han sido guardados exitosamente! "
                        . "Su cita está siendo procesada. Por favor, revise su email con frecuencia. "
                        . "Recibirá la confirmación a la mayor brevedad posible. ");
                redirect("user/profile", "refresh");
            }
        }


        $this->load->view('profile');
    }
```

**View (Edit)**

```
<div class="col-md-4">

        <!-- <input id="acciones" name="acciones" placeholder="P.ej: cargar" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text"> -->
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="acciones">-Seleccione acción-</label>    
                            <select id="acciones" name="acciones">
                                <?php
                                if (isset($acciones) && $acciones != array()) {
                                    foreach ($acciones as $accion) {
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $accion->idAcciones; ?>" <?php echo set_select('acciones', $accion->idAcciones); ?>>
                                        <?php echo $class->nombreAccion; ?>
                                        </option>
    <?php }
} ?>
                            </select>

                            <span class="help-block"> </span>  
                        </div>
```

**Controller (solved)**

```
//Le pasamos la lista a la vista para poder 
        $query = $this->User_model->get_listado_acciones();
        $item['acciones'] = $query;



        if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

       [...]


        $this->load->view('profile',$item);
    }
```

**Model (query to get acciones)**

```
 public function get_listado_acciones() {

        $query = $this->db->get('acciones');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: first you get acciones record then populate dropdown

Comment: what is your $acciones?

Comment: if you want pass data from controller to view u need to use `$this->load->view('profile',$data);` which $data is/are array
Example : $data["acciones"] = containt-data-array-or-somethin-from-your-model

Comment: Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get data from your database for $acciones. and keep make variable in your controller $data['acciones'] = $acciones; // data you got from your database through model.

than pass $data parameter with loading view as 2nd parameter.

$this->load->view('profile', $data);

in this way your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks! now it is working! i made a query through the model asking for full list.

Comment: my pleasure. keep enjoy your coding.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to get acciones record then populate the dropdown.
I think you have done mistake while generating dropdown.
Foreach is execute after select tag

```
 <!-- <input id="acciones" name="acciones" placeholder="P.ej: cargar" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text"> -->
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="acciones">-Seleccione acción-</label>    
                                <select id="acciones" name="acciones">
                            <?php
             if(isset($acciones) && $acciones!=array()){
              foreach ($acciones as $accion) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $accion->idAcciones; ?>" <?php echo set_select('acciones', $accion->idAcciones); ?>>

                                            <?php echo $class->nombreAccion; ?>
                                        </option>
                          <?php }} ?>
                                    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you! it is showing the select at least, but i have inserted data into database and select is not populating. I will update the question with current code.

Comment: @Jose. Ok,Where you define `$acciones`?

Comment: Look at the question, i have added two new blocks, i made a query in the model and got full list of acciones and then pass in the controller class. `$query = $this->User_model->get_listado_acciones();
        $item['acciones'] = $query;`

Comment: Ok Then use `$item['accinoes']` instead of `$acciones`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you might have been missed out.

From your Controller:

1.Forgot to pass the data from controller to your view :

```
    $data['acciones'] = array(); // your data here
    $this->load->view('profile' , $data); //
```

2.Your data will only be viewed if registered `button` is clicked:

```
 $data['acciones'] = array();
 if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
   echo 'test'; //try to echo here
   $data['acciones'] = array('has entry');
 }
 $this->load->view('profile' , $data); //
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean with 'has entry'? what should i put there?

Comment: That is just a test entry. That is in array because this will be the result in your `foreach` in your view page.